# Hide button for few seconds onclick

Tags: javascript, html

i want to disable button on click for few seconds, and show an image during this time, then hide the image and show the button again.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate();" name="myButton" id="myButton">  
<img style="display: none;" src="/images/loading.gif" id="myImage">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validate(){

var  myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');
var  myImage= document.getElementById('myImage');

                        setTimeout (function(){
                          myButton.style.display ='none';
                        },5000);
                      setTimeout (function(){
                          myImage.style.display ='inline';
                        },5000);
}
```

**ISSUE:**

1. This js code is not executed onclick, but after the action of this button is invoked (using JSF 2)
2. When this code is invoked, the button gets hidden and the image appears, but never get's hidden again, and the button is not getting displayed again.

please advise how to fix that.

Comment: Submit will reload the page or submit the form - you need to change it to a button or target the form to another frame/iframe/window or use ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually hiding the button and showing the image after 5 seconds, then not changing it back. Try this:

```
function validate(){

    var myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');
    var myImage= document.getElementById('myImage');

    myButton.style.display ='none';
    myImage.style.display ='inline';

    setTimeout (function(){
        myButton.style.display ='inline';
        myImage.style.display ='none';
    },5000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean

```
                    setTimeout (function(){
                      myButton.style.display ='none';
                      setTimeout (function(){
                        setTimeout (function(){
                          myButton.style.display ='none';
                        },5000);
                        myImage.style.display ='inline';
                      },5000);

                    },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You added code only for hiding the button and displaying the image. The function should look like this:

```
function validate(){

  var  myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');
  var  myImage= document.getElementById('myImage');

  var hide_timeout = 5000; // delay 5 sec before hide button;
  var show_timeout = 10000; // delay 10 sec before show button;

  setTimeout (function(){
    myButton.style.display ='none';
    myImage.style.display ='inline';
  },hide_timeout);

  setTimeout (function(){
    myButton.style.display ='inline';
    myImage.style.display ='none';    
  },show_timeout);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweaks:

```
function validate() {
  var  myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');
  var  myImage= document.getElementById('myImage');

  myButton.style.visibility='hidden';
  myImage.style.display ='inline';

  setTimeout (function(){
    myImage.style.display ='none';
    myButton.style.visibility ='visible';
  },5000);

  return false;
}
```