# Simple Redirect Page With Click Button To Continue

Tags: php, javascript

I need to create a dynamic redirector page that I can put ads banner and a call button that appears after 5 seconds. When I click the button, it will redirect to any URL after ?

For example :

1 - user click a link in website :
   - http://www.mydomain.com/go.php?http://www.google.com

2 - go.php loads a landing page with 5 seconds countdown timer show up

3 - after 5 seconds, a button appears...user can click the button to go to actual link

I manage to get the simple code..but I don't want it to automatically redirect...

```
<?php
$redirect = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
          content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
    <title>Your Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    setTimeout("location.href ='<?php echo $redirect ?>'",500);
</script>
</html>
```

You can refer to oneclickmoviez.com and try to click any download link for my example.. try this : http://oneclickmoviez.com/dws/TURBOBIT/51776/7

I'm not too expert in php coding, so I hope you can show me 100% working codes.

Comment: You can do that by working arround with html element using javascript. This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817203/hide-button-for-few-seconds-onclick

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to study little more about javascript.
I made a following sample which might meet your requirement, but you still need to know how this works to fit it in your project.

I'll recommend you to study following things to understand what I did -

1. Javascript setTimeout() - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
2. Javascript getElementById() - http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php
3. Javascript innerHTML - http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

.

```
<?php
$redirect = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'';
?>
<html><head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Your Page title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="buttonArea">
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadButton()
    {
      button = document.getElementById('buttonArea');
      button.innerHTML ='<button onclick="document.location=\'<?php echo $redirect ?>\'">Continue</button>';
    }

setTimeout(loadButton(),5000);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript timeout ins setTimeout is in miliseconds, so it should be 5000 for 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout ( expression, 5000 );
```

I would suggest use function expression, like this:

```
setTimeout ( function() {
    /* code in here */
}, 5000 );
```

And least, use `window.location` like this

```
setTimeout ( function() {
    window.location = '<?php echo $redirect ?>';
}, 5000 );
```