# Hide a button every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have searched it on google, and I have found some examples.
I have tried to do my code based on this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817203/hide-button-for-few-seconds-onclick)

I'm trying to generate a random number between 0 and 100 by clicking a button,
then hide the button and show it again after 24h.

For my example, I have inserted 5 secs for testing purposes,
But I'm getting an error from the `var` variable.

> I have just edited it, but the button is hidden and no random number is shown.
> and is not showing again
> What I'm missing here?

```
<html>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate();" name="windaily" id="windaily">
<?php $randn = rand(0,100);?>
<?php echo($randn); ?>
<script>
function validate() {
  var windaily= document.getElementById('windaily');


  windaily.style.visibility='hidden';


  setTimeout (function(){
    


    windaily.style.visibility ='visible';
  },5000);

  return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well yes i have the variable which store a  rand number i will need to access this variable later but how do i hide the button and echo my value inside of the javascript code

Comment: why do you need to use php to create a random number instead of using javascript to create a random number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require_once 'hide-button.php'; // to reset button when 24 hours has expired

    if(empty($_SESSION['hide_button'])) {
        ?><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate();" name="windaily" id="windaily"><?php
    }

    $randn = rand(0,100);
?>

<div id="display-number"></div>

<script>
    function validate() {
        let windaily = document.getElementById('windaily');
        windaily.style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById("display-number").textContent = '<?php echo $randn ?>';

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/hide-button.php", //to use php session to hide button for 24 hours
        }).done(function( msg ) {

        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then inside hide-button.php

```
<?php

if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

$expire = 86400; // 1 day

if(empty($_SESSION['timestamp'])) {
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
    $_SESSION['hide_button'] = true;
} else {
    if(time() > ($_SESSION['timestamp'] + $expire)) {
        unset($_SESSION['timestamp']);
        unset($_SESSION['hide_button']);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use php tags to override scripts.. Use the script tag and then you  can place your php variables
Substitute <? Php to

Comment: Try to include a quick code example to underline your statement !